# In Dart, is it possible to upcast a generic function?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'll start with the code since I'm having a hard time describing this problem without it.

```dart
typedef Future<S> EventFunction<E extends Event, S extends State>(E event);

abstract class State { }
abstract class Event { }

class FooState extends State { }
class FooEvent extends Event { }

void main() {
  withEvent(foo);
}

void withEvent(EventFunction func) { }

Future<FooState> foo(FooEvent event) { }
```

Seeing this code I assume that I'm allowed to call `withEvent` using any function that returns a `Future` with a type that extends `State` and any instance that inherits from `Event`. However, the compiler claims that they are not the same type, which they are not, but they are compatible. Is this a limitation in Dart itself or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**
In response to Rémi who pointed out that I was defining `withEvents`wrongly:
Defining `withEvent` as `void withEvent<E extends Event, S extends State>(EventFunction<E, S> func) { }` I am allowed to call it with the desired arguments, however, I am also allowed to call it with something like `Future<FooState> bar(int event)` which is undesirable as `int` does not extend `Event`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the definition of your `withEvent` function:

```
void withEvent(EventFunction func) { }
```

This doesn't do what you expect. It is equivalent to:

```
void withEvent(EventFunction<dynamic, dynamic> func) { }
```

You need to make `withEvent` generic too:

```
void withEvent<E extends Event, S extends State>(EventFunction<E, S> func) { }
```

Comment: While this does allow me to call `withEvent` with `foo` I'm also allowed to call it with something like `Future<FooState> bar(int event)` which is undesirable as `int` does not extend `Event`. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: That's unexpected. It seems like an issue in dart type inference.

Comment: It's very unexpected. I'd have assumed it could infer the type properly, but I guess not. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that `withEvent<int, FooState>(whatever)` won't compile with a `int is not a subtype of Event`. So one solution is to enable a linter flag to force you to specify it when the inference doesn't work.

Comment: Would that force me to specify the type for every generic method, or can I enable that linter on this specific method only?

Comment: It will force you to specify it whenever the type inference fails. See `implicit-dynamic`

Comment: I'm actually already using that. And it does not help. This is most frustrating.

Comment: Are you using it in all of its variations? Because otherwise, the linter would have told you the same thing that I did in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you are trying is correct and should works. The thing is, dart being type safe you'd have to specify `generics arguments` if a function type accepts any.

Here, your `EventFunction` event function accepts two generic type arguments which are missing at `withEvent` definition.

Just change your,

```
void withEvent(EventFunction func) { } // dart infers EventFunction = EventFunction<dynamic,dynamic> when no generic arguments passed
```

to,

```
void withEvent(EventFunction<FooEvent,FooState> func) { }
```

This should work. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for you input Hemanth! You can see my update or my response to Rémi's answer about this solution, it does not meet my needs.